# Loss Function of generator in Gans

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have studies the gans in depth and have also implemented it in pytorch, now I am studying the core statistics behind gans, when I was looking at that website [Mathematics behing Gans](http://www.shashwatverma.com/math-behind-generative-adversarial-networks.html)
it said

> "Loss(G) = - Loss(D), Notice that we defined the generators cost as negative of discriminator’s cost. This is because we do not have an explicit way to evaluate a generator’s cost."

But when implement gan we define the loss for generator as:

> Bintropy Cross entropy loss between the discriminator output for the images produced by generator and Real labels as in the Original Paper and following code (implemented and tested by me)

```
    # train generator
    z_ = to.randn(minibatch,100 ).view(-1, 100, 1, 1)
    z_ = Variable(z_.cuda())
    gen_images = generator(z_)

    D_fake_decisions = discriminator(gen_images).squeeze()
    G_loss = criterion(D_fake_decisions,real_labels)

    discriminator.zero_grad()
    generator.zero_grad()
    G_loss.backward()
    opt_Gen.step()
```

Please explain me the difference the difference between the two, and the right one

Code Link : https://github.com/mabdullahrafique/Gan_with_Pytorch/blob/master/DCGan_mnist.ipynb

Thanks

Comment: Binary Cross Entropy is not the loss of Generator but it's for Discriminator. I am writing a little explanation in answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discriminator's job is to perform Binary Classification to detect between Real and Fake so its loss function is Binary Cross Entropy.

What Generator does is Density Estimation, from the noise to real data, and feed it to Discriminator to fool it.

The approach followed in the design is to model it as MinMax game. Now let's have a look at cost functions:

[image: Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/generative-adversarial-networks-history-and-overview-7effbb713545]

Someone explained this as:

> The first term in J(D) represents feeding the actual data to the discriminator, and the discriminator would want to maximize the log probability of predicting one, indicating that the data is real. The second term represents the samples generated by G. Here, the discriminator would want to maximize the log probability of predicting zero, indicating the the data is fake. The generator, on the other hand tries to minimize the log probability of the discriminator being correct. The solution to this problem is an equilibrium point of the game, which is a saddle point of the discriminator loss.

Since the Discriminator tries to maximize the probability of Generator's sample as Zero, the Generator's job becomes to maximize for one. This is equivalent to making the Generator’s cost function the negative cross entropy, where the first term in J(D) would now be constant.

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/generative-adversarial-networks-history-and-overview-7effbb713545